# Is there a Chrome (browser) extension like FireFTP from Firefox?

Tags: ftp, google-chrome-extensions

Is there a Chrome (browser) extension like FireFTP from Firefox?

I've tried to find it without success

Comment: I know this is quite an old question, but there is an FTP/SSH app on Google Chrome here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sftp-client/jajcoljhdglkjpfefjkgiohbhnkkmipm

Answer (score 6):

Before you answer the question, you must know what FireFTP is!

1. FireFTP is not like ftp://example.com
2. FireFTP is not like net2ftp or chromeftp

FireFTP doesn't need to access any external website, FireFTP, similarly to FileZilla, directly accesses your FTP Server using Firefox. FireFTP has 2 panels like Norton Commander.

In short, there is no app like FireFTP in Chrome! Sadly, but it's true at the moment I'm writing this.

NOTE: That's why many users still use Firefox because FireFTP is very helpful!!!

Answer (score 5):

An alternative might be to use a 3rd party website such as http://www.net2ftp.com

Again, not hugely exciting.  Both the obvious looking "FTP" chrome extensions (Chrome FTP & FTP Client) are pretty poor, but you never know, YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

I have put together a site using the net2ftp script that works pretty well. I put it behind and SSL so it is also secure.

http://chromeftp.com

[image]

Comment: -1 broken link.

Comment: How is this safe? Aren't the credentials submitted to your server?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, slim pickings, I'm afraid.

You can use Chrome's built-in FTP client, but it's pretty basic.  eg:  ftp://anonymous:password@ftp.redhat.com/redhat/linux/

(You can skip the "username:password@" prefix and Chrome will prompt you for them instead.)

Comment: put "username:password" into the url if you reference it later...

Comment: I think this is a step in the right direction. I just wish that either a Chrome extension would feed off of this and enhance it more, or Google would improve this system so that I can read/write files and folders, rename things, delete things, and change permissions.

Comment: No longer an answer I'm afraid.

Answer (score -3):

You just open a new tab or window and write your FTP address. It will then ask for the user and password details. You don't need to download any program or extension.

Comment: The FTP browser is read-only, so does a fraction of what FireFTP does